# Integer solutions for $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}=\frac{p}{q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, diophantine-equations

I found a description of the way to solve $$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}=\frac{p}{q}$$, for relatively prime $p,q$ in integers that goes as follows:

> Write the LHS as $\frac{a+b}{ab}$. Let $a=\frac{m+q}{p}, b=\frac{n+q}{p}$. Hence, $$\frac{a+b}{ab}=p\cdot \frac{m+n+2q}{q^2+(m+n)q+mn}=\frac{p}{q}$$. Thus, we see that the big fraction must be equal $\frac{1}{q}$. Thus, $q(m+n+2q)=q^2+(m+n)q+mn$, so $mn=q^2$. The solutions are generated as follows: list all ways to write $q^2$ as a product $mn$ of integers, keep only those for which $p$ divides $q+m$ and $q+n$ (since $a$ and $b$ are integers), and the solutions are $a=(m+q)/p$, $b=(n+q)/p$.

The only thing I don't understand is why we assume that $a=\frac{m+q}{p}, b=\frac{n+q}{p}$.  This step seems completely arbitrary to me. Why do all solutions to the equation have this form? What is the motivation to make this substituiton?

Comment: You don't have to put $a=(m+q)/p$. It makes much more sense to define $m:=ap-q$. Then of course, because $p\neq 0$ it follows directly that $a=(m+q)/p$. Similarly define $n:=bp-q$.

Comment: You just have to define $m=pa-q$ and $n=pb-q$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What's so special about these? I still don't see how anyone could see that these substituions help to solve the problem.

Comment: The substitutions are just made so that you can decompose $q^2=mn$ in all possible ways etc. So this is one possibility to generate all solutions. Of course there are others. You can try a different substitution (do it with  concrete examples of $p$ and $q$ first. For example, find all solutions $a,b$ for $1/a+1/b=7/9$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm much more confused about how anyone could come up with this approach. Like, "Oh, the solutions must be somehow related to the factors of $q^2$, so these substitutions relate $a,b$ to factors of $q^2$." But why should I think about factors of $q^2$ in the first place?

Comment: Did you try an explicit example? Then you see what happens. Try it yourself to solve, say, $1/a+1/b=7/9$ with your own method, and then with the one explained, i.e., with $m:=7a-9$ and $n:=7b-9$. You learn much more by doing something yourself than by posting.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your responses. I did try examples. There are no solutions to your examples, but I found some to the $1/a+1/b=3/10$. But I got no new intuition. I could see from the general form that $mn=(pa-q)(pb-q)=p^2 ab - pq(a+b) + q^2 = q^2$, since $pab=q(a+b)$. But I still fail to understand how I could think of this approach in the first place. Maybe I just lack experience. Whatever, thank you for your time.

Comment: You understand much better when there is a solution at all and how to find them by clearing the denominators and using that $p$ and $q$ are coprime than with this substitution. The necessary and sufficient condition that there are distinct $a,b$ doing the job is that there is a divisor $t\mid q^2$ ($t<q$) , such that $p\mid q+t$. Try to work that out.

Comment: In your example, $100=2\cdot 50$ leads to $1/4+1/20=3/10$, so $t=2$ and $t=50$ work.

Comment: Are negative integers also allowed ? In this case, my comment has to be modified. It holds , if $a,b$ must be positive and $p,q$ are also positive.

Comment: @Peter Can you help me prove the necessary condition? I'm still stuck with understanding the problem. I think the necessary condition could answer my question as to why every solution looks like that, so you could even write it as an answer I could probably accept. Let's say only positive integers are allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For which coprime positive integers $p,q$ ($p<q$) does $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{p}{q}$$ have a solution in distinct positive integers $a,b$ (the case $a=b$ works if and only if $p\le 2$) ?

Claim : There must be a divisor $t\mid q^2$ with $t<q$ such that $p\mid q+t$

Proof : Clearing the denominators gives

$$qa+qb=pab$$

Mutlplying with $p$ and rearranging gives

$$p^2ab-pqa-pqb=0$$

So, we have

$$(pa-q)(pb-q)=p^2ab-pqa-pqb+q^2=q^2$$

Hence $t:=pa-q$ is a divisor of $q^2$ , implying $p\mid q+t$. If $a$ and $b$ are distinct, the smaller divisor is smaller than $q$.

QED

This condition is also sufficient :

Assume, $t<q$ is a divisor of $q^2$ such that $p\mid q+t$.

Then $$pa-q=t$$ can be satisfied with the positive integer $a:=\frac{q+t}{p}$. It remains to show that for the cofactor $\frac{q^2}{t}$ , the corresponding $b$ is also a positive integer : We have $$\frac{\frac{q^2}{t}+q}{p}=\frac{q}{t}\cdot \frac{q+t}{p}$$ $p$ and $t$ are coprime because $q$ shares each common factor of $p$ and $t$ , but $p$ and $q$ are coprime. Since $t$ and $p$ both divide $q^2+qt$ , the product divides it as well. Because of $t<q$ , we finally have $a<b$

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{p}{q}
=\frac{a+b}{ab}$$
there is always a solution when

$$|xp|=|a+b|\space\land\space |yq|=|ab|\qquad a,b,p,q,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$$